# Using Swift to send data to a Python server under UDP

Tags: python, ios, swift, networking, udp

iOS 13, Swift 5, Xcode 11

Running a python udp server.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

port = 31766

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', port))
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 1500)
print("listening on port ",port)

while True:
    compressed_data, server = s.recvfrom(1500)
    print(compressed_data)
```

Can connect with UDP client.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket

UDP_IP = "192.168.1.1"
UDP_PORT = 31766 
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
print "message:", MESSAGE

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
         socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

But when I try and run a BONJOUR service

```
dns-sd -R wow _wow._udp local 31766
```

I can see it with my iOS.
I can see it with OSX.
I can connect with no errors and send data with this code ....

```
func connectToUDP(name: String) {
  self.talking = NWConnection(to: .service(name: name, type: "_wow._udp", domain: "local", interface: nil), using: .udp)

  self.talking?.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
  switch (newState) {
  case .ready:
    print("ready to send")
    self.sendUDP("Boo")
  default:
    print("damn")
  }
}
self.talking?.start(queue: .main)
}
```

My server works ok, cause I see data coming thru when the python sending script is run. But when I try and send data thru the swift code I see nothing.

Some more notes on this. If I change the NWConnection so that it looks like this, it works.

```
self.talking = NWConnection(host: "192.168.1.110", port: 31766, using: .udp)
```

But the point is I lose the bonjour service effectively.  Note I use this command to check that the bonjour service is running.

```
dns-sd -B _wow._udp
```

> returns
>       Browsing for _wow._udp
>       DATE: ---Fri 07 Feb 2020---
>       12:08:41.387  ...STARTING...
>       Timestamp     A/R    Flags  if Domain               Service Type             Instance Name
>       12:08:41.388  Add        3   1 local.               _wow._udp.           wow
>       12:08:41.388  Add        3   4 local.               _wow._udp.           wow
>       12:08:41.388  Add        2   5 local.               _wow._udp.           wow

And I use this command to check it is returning the correctly parameters

```
dig -p 5353 @224.0.0.251 wow._wow._udp.local. SRV +short
```

> returns
>         0 0 31766 Home-3.local.

More debug. I downloaded, compiled and used this as a server on my OS X. It works.

[OSX Network Framework](https://rderik.com/blog/building-a-server-client-aplication-using-apple-s-network-framework/)

Obviously you need to change tcp in this source to UDP and comment out the back connection.

Also tried this to get the host + port thru

[Bonjour: Search for a service by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45999930/bonjour-search-for-a-service-by-name)

And than went with the second call for NWConnection, with the returned information...

```
self.talking = NWConnection(host: "Home-3.local.", port: 31766, using: .udp)
```

This works too, **But to go back to my original question. I want to try and connect to a PYTHON server**, not on iOS one or an OSX one. Incidentally here is the code for the browser under iOS which finds the service!

```
func findUDP() {
print("findUDP")
let parameters = NWParameters()
parameters.includePeerToPeer = true

browser = NWBrowser(for: .bonjour(type: "_wow._udp", domain: "local."), using: parameters)
browser?.browseResultsChangedHandler = { foo, changes in
  for change in changes {
    switch change {
    case .added(let browseResult):
      playing = browseResult.endpoint
      print(browseResult.endpoint)
    default:
      print("anything else seen")
    }
  }
}
self.browser?.start(queue: .main)
```